# Iterate through node attributes in networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I create a graph with networkx and every node has some attributes. So i want to search all nodes for a specific attributes and save every node who has this attribute in a list. I wrote the following code but im getting an error:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    for attribute in G.node[node]['attributes']:
        if attribute in question:
            setOfUsers.append(node)
```

With this code im getting the following error:

```
for attribute in G.node[node]['attributes']:
KeyError: 'attributes'
```

So i search the forum and i tried something different to fix the problem:

```
for node, data in G.nodes(data=True):
    if data['attributes'] == question[0]:
        setOfUsers.append(node)
```

but i have the same error. How can iterate through the attributes?

**Update**: I add the node attributes with the code below. I read the attributes from a file, i split commas and newline character and then i save list in nodes

```
for line in file2:
    line = line.strip()
    words = line.split('\t')
    node = int(words[0])
    attributes= words[1]
    splittedAttributes = attributes.split(',')
    if node in G.nodes():
        G.node[node]['attributes'] = splittedAttributes
```

Comment: You did not add `skills` attribute to the graph.

Comment: Are you sure *any* node has an `'attribute'` attribute?
If `node in G.nodes()` is *never* true, in the line `if node in G.nodes(): G.node[node]['attributes'] = splittedAttributes` then no `node` will be assigned an `'attributes'` attribute.

Comment: Can you print `G.nodes(data=True)` for us?

Comment: @anutbu yes i think that this is the problem. I have some nodes that they dont have attributes. How can i fix this? Is it a goof idea to add a space as attribute?

Answer (score 7):

are your sure you have added the info to your nodes previously? it seems like networkX doesn't known anything about your 'attributes'. by adding the info i mean something like this:

```
for node in G.nodes():
    G.node[node]['attributes']= attributes[node]
```

then you can use your own code to examine them

```
for node in G.nodes():
    for attribute in G.node[node]['attributes']:
        if attribute in question:
            setOfUsers.append(node)
```

Comment: Needed to replace G.node[...][...] with G.nodes[...][...] to get it to work, otherwise works well.